# Error in launching AVD

Tags: android, intel, android-virtual-device, haxm

I have Windows 8.1 with an AMD processor. I installed the Android Studio 1.1.0 (with Android SDK Manager). It works but the problem is that when I run my application:

```
>emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
>CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

I have ASUS A52D. I cannot find Intel Virtualization Technology in my BIOS. 
Go to extras **> intel > Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager and run the file named "intelhaxm-android.exe"**. Have an error: This computer does not support Intel Virtualization (VT-x). HAMX cannot be installed. How I can run my application without using hardware acceleration?

Comment: Use ARM system image instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the HAXM emulator on AMD hardware, and this is not possible.  You can only run HAXM on Intel (x86, or x64) processors.

You simply have the wrong hardware for this functionality.

You will be able to run any other emulator, that isn't setup to be HAXM enabled (it will be slower, but it will work).